# Getting boxes to same width in Firefox using -moz-box

Tags: css, firefox, width

I am using the following css to get three evenly spaced and sized boxes with a flexible width:

```
.box {
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.box2, .box3 {  
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

The html is in the form:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

You can see the page I am using this on [here](http://www.bodhitreebrighton.org.uk/about.html).

This works fine in Safari, but in Firefox the width of the boxes are not even. Rather the first box in each row is just wide enough to fit the content and the second two boxes take up the rest of the width.  I wonder if someone could help me with this CSS to get it working in Firefox.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `width:0` is the *current* way to lay out flexible boxes (from http://hotmeteor.com/2011/04/22/equals-widths-using-the-css3-flexible-box-layout-module/)

Changing the `.box1, .box2, .box3` CSS selector's `width:30%` to `width:0` fixes Firefox layout and still works in Chrome.